# How to collect results from multiple azure app services and push to a topic

Tags: azure, architecture, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have 3 Azure service bus topics, 3 azure app services subscribe to these topic messages and perform some actions and return results.

I want to push a message to another topic with the collective results (failure/success) from the above 3 app services.

How can this be achieved?

The sample flow chart below:

[image: Sample flowchart]

Comment: Do all the 3 events from initial topic share some common id? As i am not sure about the scenario, can share a rough idea.

as 3 events might not reach/ get processed at the same time, so you need some intermittent storage, where you can store the result of each service (e.g. any No SQL). once you receive all result (keep on checking upon receiving each serie result if all 3 are done or not using the common Id). Once all 3 received , then do your processing with a Function app & push it to another queue using output binding.  Its might not be a great idea , but it's an idea. :)

Comment: @lokanathdas yes, thanks for sharing. Coz I was thinking of doing the same. Now I know its a viable solution :)

Comment: I’d add a 5th message to the mix, a timeout. Rather than polling all the time, you’d set up a timeout that would verify completion, later check or compensating action should one of the 3 services failed providing its status.

Comment: Yes in my case polling in the sense, lets assume a cosmos trigger function will be listening to the each data comes to Cosmos databse. So just query to Cosmos if all 3 event reached or not . Once 3rd event reaches upon querying process will get to know all 3 event reached then processing will start. So it will be a cosmos db check. Instead of polling & checking from topic directly. As per cosmos is concerned unless you do upsert it's not a costly call to make. But yes need to have a proper disaster recovery options to make sure not loosing any event.

Comment: @SeanFeldman not thinking of polling. All 3 worker svcs will push response to topic 4. Final handler would subscribe to topic 4, on each msg on topic 4 it would ping db to see if all are done. So in this case it would hit db thrice for 3 msgs on topic 4. Hope it makes sense

Comment: @SeanFeldman how do you suggest to implement timeout msg, could you rephrase pls?

Comment: I never suggested how to implement it, rather that it would be helpful as you don’t control the time and want to ensure there’s a compensating action should one of the 3 services fails to produce a result. Implementation details would highly demand on the services you’ll use. But even with ASB you could achieve the desired outcome. If it helps, I could prototype pure ASB option and share as an answer.

Comment: @SeanFeldman yes am using ASB. I am open to suggestions for any other services of azure. If you could answer it would be of great help. Thank u.

Comment: You don't really need another service. I'm writing a blog post on this and will share the link here.

Comment: @SeanFeldman sounds good. Thanks.

Comment: @User3250, are you heading the last service wait time solely on fine or number of retries with back-off time?

Comment: @SeanFeldman currently the only strategy is monitoring the DLQ. Last service is triggered by queue msg.Waits endlessly for new messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the options to solve this is to leverage the Azure Service Bus Message Sessions feature. It allows handling messages and keeping the state using a single service. You'd have 3 message types (events) published by the upstream services (Payment, Email, and Notification), and a fourth message type, a timeout. This is also known as a saga pattern. I've described the implementation with Azure Service Bus in detail in this [blog post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/sagas-with-azure-service-bus).